# Deploying ASP.NET Core WebAPI Or .NET Framework on Apache server on Windows

Tags: asp.net, apache, asp.net-core, mono, mod-mono

I want to host an (ASP.NET Core WebAPI) or (.NET Framework Web Application) on Apache Server on Windows.

i searched for solutions and i found a module called mod_aspdotnet but i can't seem to find any tutorials on how to use it in windows for the above situation.

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you find any thing for this? as i have same requirements.Thx.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try using the Apache server as a reverse proxy server, follow the Microsoft's article [Host ASP.NET Core on Linux with Apache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x),

Or with mod_aspdotnet, check their home page at [mod_aspdotnet module for Apache HTTP Server 2.x](http://mod-aspdotnet.sourceforge.net/) for introduction.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.